# Java Interview Question: finalize() method

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

I was given the following phrase in an interview:

> The invocation of an Object's
>   finalize() method is the last thing
>   that happens before an object is
>   garbaged collected.

I had to answer by:

- True
- False

I've chosen `True` but it was wrong.
Can you please explain me why ?

Comment: Please read this article: 
http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0051.shtml

Comment: @Vash, that article is very out-of-date

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The order is different:

1. **First** the object is **collected**.
2. **Then** the object is **finalized**.

See http://java.dzone.com/articles/ocajp-7-object-lifecycle-java

> Object lifecycle:
>
> 1. Created
> 2. In use (strongly reachable)
> 3. Invisible
> 4. Unreachable
> 5. *Collected*
> 6. *Finalized*
> 7. Deallocated

Comment: Confirmed. *collected* is not the final state of the object's life cycle, it is *deallocated*. +1 for the link and learning something today :)

Comment: The problem with this is that “collected” is a colloquial term which is interpreted differently. Some people say “collected” to refer to the event that a garbage collector determines that an object is not reachable, others use the same word to say that an object’s memory has been reclaimed. Depending on this subjective meaning, the answer is different. In the specification, there is no such thing as a  “collected” state.

Answer (score 8):

I think it hints that the fact that there are actually other things that can be done / happen to the object before the GC really discards it.

**To quote the reference:**

> [...]The finalize method may take any
>   action, including making this object
>   **available again to other threads**; the usual purpose of finalize,
>   however, is to perform cleanup actions
>   **before the object is irrevocably discarded**. For example, the finalize
>   method for an object that represents
>   an input/output connection might
>   perform explicit I/O transactions to
>   break the connection **before the
>   object is permanently
>   discarded.**[...]

So in this light, the finalizing process isn't the last thing before the GC discards it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that `finalize()` will always be called, or even that garbage collection will run at all.

Suppose that your program ends (either by calling `System.exit()` or when all running threads reach their end), then the JVM will just quit, it won't clean everything up and call `finalize()` on all objects.

Therefore, putting cleanup tasks that absolutely must run in a `finalize()` method is not a good idea.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: It partly answers the question and gives some useful information about why `finalize()` isn't as useful as many programmers think.

Comment: it might be nice to spray useful trivia around, but it's even nicer to stick to the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even though is not an exact answer it's a nice to know trivia.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can defend both answers, `finalize()` is called by the garbage collector before it collects the object, but you cannot be sure that will ever be the case before the apllication ends. Not all objects that are allegible to be garbage collected have to be colected. You may never depend on the `finalize()` method to be called for any object.

Answer (score 1):

The order is wrong, as [DR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306883/java-interview-question-finalize-method/3306921#3306921) already showed.

An object changes its state to *collected* when the gc has recognized, that the object is unreachable.

So *who* should take action to finalize an object before this 'unreachable' condition was detected? In fact it's the garbage collector that marks collected objects for finalization (if the objects finalize method is overridden). And we really don't want to finalize objects that are still reachable, e.g. 'in use'.

Nice question anyway, because you tend to say 'yes it's true'.

Answer (score 0):

You can resurrect the object in the finalize method by making something point to it so the object may not be collected by the GC after calling finalized method. but when the object again becomes available for garbage collection it wont call the finalized method of that object as it has been marked/flagged as finalized. so before GC it may happen the call finalize method or the object can resurrect.